# Salesforce Commerce cloud B2C Import catalog issue

Tags: import

I am facing issue while **importing product csv sheet** through catalog import in merchant tools
Products are being added but with only few field
**ISSUE:**
WARN Import CSV File validation warning. Attribute ID 'Description' does not exist. Skipping column.
File validation warning. Attribute ID 'name' is missing site or locale suffix. Skipping column.

So are the product attribute names not correct or missing a essential attribute?

And are there other ways to import catalog in salesforce ecommerce cloud using tool or url..please let me know.

Thank you!!